# How do i parse this URL with beautiful Soup? What format is the URL?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to crawl some data from this type of url:

> http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29/render?start=0&count=5&currency=&language=english

I don't know, it contains some kind of html-tags but i don't know how to actually scrape this page (i used beautifulSoup for my other urls).

Hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you loaded is a JSON file. Use the [JSON library](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/json/) **like so**:

```
import requests
import json

html = requests.get('http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29/render?start=0&count=5&currency=&language=english')

# Load the parsed page into a JSON object.
steam_json = json.loads(html.text)

# Extract whatever you want like this:
success_status = steam_json['success']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
The `requests.get`command is python2 i assume? Do you know the command for python3? could it be `urllib.request.urlopen(url)` ?

Comment: The script above was tested in Python 3. Make sure you have requests installed via pip.

Comment: Your way would be:
`html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29/render?start=0&count=5&currency=&language=english').read()`

And then make sure you remove the appending `.text` when you create the JSON object from the `html` variable.

Comment: Great! That worked. I had to `.decode('utf-8'))` but it's fine now :) I'll continue tomorrow with filtering out the data i need from the HTML.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Don't import json and then use json as a variable name, also you don't need json at all considering you can simply call html.json()

Comment: I agree, poor variable name choice. The reason I used the json library was to leave the parsing of the input separate from whatever method was used to gather that data.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do it with python, i.e. jsoup is a BeautifulSoup-like library for Java. The url returns a [json](http://www.json.org/). Your first have to load it as a python-native instance. In this case the corresponding python-native object is a [dictionary](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm), using the json library:

```
import json, urllib2 
request  = urllib2.Request(url=your_url)
request.add_header('User-agent',user_agent) # let's say you want to add headers like user-agent etc...
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
dico = json.loads(response.read())
```

Then you have to explore the key-value pairs which are of interest for you, and parse the values containing html as you usually do with beautifulSoup.

Also, note that the site from which you want to get data, can be hypermedia-driven (see [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS)), which is a kind of [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) implemented with no graphical interface. Whatever it might be, it allows you to be more precise (and thus more server-friendly) in the data you request.

```
url_base = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29/render?" 
start = 0
count = 5
currency = ''
language = 'english'
your_url = url_base + "start={0}&count={1}&currency={2}&language={3}".format(start,count,currency,language)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I tried it out and got the Error message:  
 > TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'. 
I tried to work around this problem with: 

`response = urllib.request.urlopen(euro_url)  
    str_response = response.read().decode('utf-8')  
    obj = json.loads(str_response) `  I think it works now :-x